# Can you explain how the angular filter process works with this code?

Tags: angularjs, filter

I don't understand why the .name is happening in the model instead of the filter. I don't get what is happening behind the scenes when I create nameText.name and bind it to my data. How is my filter actually working?

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="nameText.name" />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="nameText.city" />
<li data-ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:nameText>

<script>
function FilteringController($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [
        { name: 'Dave Jones', city: 'Phoenix' },
        { name: 'Jamie Riley', city: 'Phoenix' },
        { name: 'Heedy Wahlin', city: 'Chandler' },
        { name: 'Thomas Winter', city: 'Seattle' }
    ];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nameText` is an object with the properties `name` and `city` in this case. These properties are filled by the input fields. You're filtering your list using an object. What Angular does in this case, is filter the objects in the list using the properties with the matching names. So, for example, if `nameText.city` is `Phoenix`, the items in the list are filtered so that only the items with `Phoenix` for the `city` property are left. This works the same for `name` and both can be combined.

**Update to answer question in comments**: For the exact implementation, I'd suggest looking through the Angular source code. The specific case for a filter using an object is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filter.js#L165). What this roughly does is get all the properties of the object passed in as the filter (`nameText` in your case). It then goes through the list of objects to filter and select all the objects that have properties with values that match the properties that you are searching for. In the source code I referred, you can also see how the other types of search filters you may pass would be handled.

Comment: So this nameText is an object, with these properties name and city, and let's say I type in "John" for the name, so we get nameText={name: "John"}. Does it even have a city field if I don't put anything in the city input box? Then the filter goes looking for the object nameText, and how exactly does it work, it goes behind the scenes and finds all the stuff with the name "John" and displays that, what is happening with the code between the model and the filter..

Comment: @HyeShusho, see my updated answer for a more detailed explanation. Until the city input has been touched, the property probably doesn't exist, but that's easy enough to verify for yourself (just print the search object on the page).